# cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'context:component- scan'

Tags: xml, spring

I am trying to integrate JPA with springframework, but it is giving an error. 
Could some one help to resolve this issue. I really do not what to fix.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/ http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/ http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd" >

    <!-- It register the beans in context and scan the annotations inside beans and activate them -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mycircle.dao"></context:component-scan>

    <!-- This allow for dispatching requests to Controllers -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that URI used in the namespace declaration differs from URI used in schemaLocation (the slash at the end):

```
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"

xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/ http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd"
```

Both URIs must be the same.

Hope it helps.